# Referencing Specific Location in My Data

Tags: r

I am new to R and trying to solve a problem.

Here is an example of my data:

```
product_id             week           purchases
      53                0                   19              
      53                1                   27               
      53                2                   34                   
      53                3                   43                
      53                4                   44
```

For this data, there are three types of product_id, and the week variable runs from 0-15 for each, with a positive purchase value for each.

I would like to add a third variable called percent, and would like it to equal Purchases / the value of purchases when week = 15, for the relevant product data id.

My problem is I don't know how to tell R I want to refer only to week=15 & the product id of whatever row I am on, when writing this equation.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I had this in another iteration before, but accidentally deleted it; I've reposted it here, and tried to clarify what I was asking.  Much thanks for any/all help!

Comment: can you post the expected output?

Comment: For product_id == 53 && week==15, if purchases==200, I'd want a variable called percent, so that where product_id==53, week==0, percent ==.095; when product_id=53, week=1, percent==.135, etc. (.095 being 19/200, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `week==4` instead  of 15 (so it works with your example data). All these results assuming that there is only one `value == TRUE` for `week==4`

You could use `ave` (and `transform`)

```
transform(DF, prop.purchases = ave(purchases, product_id, FUN = function(x) x/ x[week==4]))
```

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(DF)
DT[, prop.purchase := purchases / purchases[week==4], by = product_id]
```

an alternative approach using keys and `by-without-by`

```
DT <- data.table(DF, key = 'product_id')

DT[DT[week==4], prop.purchase := purchases / i.purchaes]
```

Using `plyr` and `ddply`

```
library(plyr)

ddply(DF, .(product_id), mutate,  prop.purchases = purchases / purchases[week==4])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the simple `ifelse` for your simple sample data works:

## the sample data is called as sample

```
sample data  (with added data for id 54 and 55: 
product_id  week    purchases
53  0   19
53  1   27
53  2   34
53  3   43
53  4   44
53  14  23
54  0   23
54  1   21
54  2   22
54  3   32
54  4   33
54  14  22
55  0   22
55  1   33
55  2   44
55  3   55
55  4   11
55  14  12


sample$percent<-with(sample,ifelse(product_id ==53, purchases/purchases[week==14 &product_id==53],ifelse(product_id ==54, purchases/purchases[week==14 & product_id==54],purchases/purchases[week==14 &product_id==55])))

Output: 
 product_id week purchases   percent
1          53    0        19 0.8260870
2          53    1        27 1.1739130
3          53    2        34 1.4782609
4          53    3        43 1.8695652
5          53    4        44 1.9130435
6          53   14        23 1.0000000
7          54    0        23 1.0454545
8          54    1        21 0.9545455
9          54    2        22 1.0000000
10         54    3        32 1.4545455
11         54    4        33 1.5000000
12         54   14        22 1.0000000
13         55    0        22 1.8333333
14         55    1        33 2.7500000
15         55    2        44 3.6666667
16         55    3        55 4.5833333
17         55    4        11 0.9166667
18         55   14        12 1.0000000
```